# How to Implement Withdrawal Functionality in Django: Integrating Razorpay and Bank Transfers

Tags: django, payment-gateway, razorpay, payment-method

I am working on a Django web application where users need to be able to withdraw money from their accounts. I am looking for assistance in implementing a withdrawal functionality within my Django project. The process involves saving the withdrawn amount to the Razorpay dashboard and then transferring it to the user's linked bank account.

Comment: Looking for assistance is off-topic on *StackOverflow*, you should ask a specific question. For example add code with a specific API endpoint and what is not working.